Doesn't pick up the ASP.NET localization file
I am working on an ASP.NET project and I need to implement localization of messages on the backend. I want to use two resource files (one for English and one for Russian) that will be common for all classes in the solution, and also use the localizer in my controllers as follows: localizer["message"]. I have configured Startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
...
// Localization
services.AddControllers().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "ru", "en" };

    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures);
});
...

Primitive structure:
Solution
│
├── Web
│   ├── Startup.cs
│   ├── Program.cs
│   ├── SharedResource.cs
│   │   Controllers
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── Resources
│   │   ├── SharedResource.en.resx
│   │   ├── SharedResource.ru.resx
│   └── ...
└── Other projects

I also created a separate class SharedResource accordingly in the controller it looks like this IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer. I have two files SharedResources.ru.resx and SharedResource.en.resx which are located in the Resources folder.
And the whole problem is that when I send a request to the API, it returns not the message, but the key specified in localizer["message"], i.e., message. As I understand it, this happens when the resource file is not found.
And I don't understand why this is happening. Thanks in advance!
Create localization in your project so that localized messages come from the backend, and you only receive the key.

In the Startup.cs, I assume that you have added this line:
app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

after the line: var app = builder.Build();.
From this statement:
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

This will automatically add postfix "Resource" to the end of the full name of the Resource file according to Resource file naming
When I try to debug with _localizer["One"].SearchedLocation, the generated value is:

<Your application name>.Resources.Resources.SharedResource

I believe that your full name (namespace) of ShareResource.resx file is:

<Your application name>.Resources.SharedResource

Thus, it can't find your file.
To avoid affecting other resource files in the Resource folder, a dirty approach is that you have to manually change the namespace in the SharedResource.Designer.cs file by removing the ".Resources":
namespace <Your web application name> {
    using System;
    
    
    ...
    public class SharedResource {

    }

}

Also, you have to change the using namespace in the .cs and .cshtml that use this SharedResource (from using <Your application name>.Resources to using <Your application name>).

Thanks for the answer, you are right - the problem is with the namespace, I took this project out of the solution and everything worked, but the problem is that my SharedResources.cs file has the namespace <App Name>.<Name Service>.Web. When I request the namespace in the resources, I get the following: Web.Resources.<App Name>.<Name Service>.Web.SharedResource, and here, as you can see, something is clearly wrong. I do not quite understand how to edit this, because specifying a custom namespace does not help.

Solved the issue by simply adding the line [assembly: RootNamespace("Namespace")] to the SharedResource.cs class. Thanks!
